# Variable populates only after Thread.Sleep(1)

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have a bizarre situation.  Here's a quick block of code:

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Pane pane in window.Panes)
{
    for (var i = 1; i <= pane.Pages.Count; i++)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Page page = null;
        bool populated = false;
        while (!populated)
        {
            try
            {
                page = pane.Pages[i];
                populated = true;
            }
            catch (COMException ex)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1);
                counter++;
            }
        }
```

For some reason, on the first run `page = pane.Pages[i]` will throw an exception. After `Thread.Sleep(1)` it populates properly.

If I remove the `while{}` loop and do a step-by-step debug, everything works. If I run it (F5) without the `while{}` loop it crashes.  I have a two part question.

1. What is going on,
2. is there a more elegant way to write this?

Should I do some research on features like volatile or locked variables? (although I don't think I can apply volatile to anything). Thank you in advance.

Oh and for those who are about to post DO NOT USE INTEROP, thank you for your sage advice, I however have no choice at this point so I will be using it :)

Comment: What is the detail of your exception? Which `HRESULT` is it?

Comment: @GrantWinney Most Office Interop stuff is one-based.

Comment: Symptoms are similar to webbrowser control running in a STA thread. You can not directly use the dom object just after setting *DocumentText*, you have to make sure *DocumentCompleted* event is fired.

Comment: Does using a `foreach(Word.Page page in pane.Pages) {}` do the same thing?

Comment: I'm not sure, haven't tried foreach since I am directly loading a variable (that doesn't even appear to have a type) called "page" via pane.Pages[i];  I suppose it could work though, but then I fear it would just zoom through the whole thing since there would be no pages in the first split second.

Comment: L.B. Any hints as to how I may deploy a DocumentCompleted solution to circumnavigate using the Sleep command?

Comment: @Lukas I never worked with word interop, but I think there should be some event notifying your objects (windows/Panes/Pane/Page) are ready.

Comment: Thanks LB, I appreciate the insight. I'll do some more digging around.